# What is the Scala way of using guard clauses to exit a function early?

Tags: scala

I am wondering if there is a idiomatic way of using guard clauses to leave a method early if a condition is met.

In other languages, I would do something like this:

```
def myFunction(): Either[String, String] = {
  if (someErrorCondition)
    return Left("error msg")

  // Rest of the code
}
```

However, this seems wrong to me, since using `return` does not seem to be the idiomatic way of doing it. I have considered this:

```
def myFunction(): Either[String, String] = {
  if (someErrorCondition)
    Left("error msg")
  else
    // Rest of the code
}
```

But it is ugly and would imply many `if-else` where multiple guards are needed.

Any suggestions on how to do this properly?

Comment: `if` without else often lead to bad type (as it returns a `Unit` in fact) ...

Comment: What is wrong with many `if-else`? However since you are using **Either** you may take advantage that it's `flatMap` short circuits on **Lefts**. There is also a helper method `Either.cond(boolean, right, left)` and chain all of them on big **for comprehension**.

Comment: IMHO there is absolutely nothing wrong with `if-else`.

Comment: I agree leading ifs are ugly and distracting. For single if, put it on one line, `def f = if (cond) fail() else {` with rest of "real body" idented normally. Otherwise stick validation in a function, `def f: Either[A,B] = validated.map(body)`.

Comment: (No one said: The question is how many ways are there in Scala to do X?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seconding others, IMHO, the idea that conditional expression are not idiomatic is a fallacy, hence the following seem OK to me

```
if (errorCondition1) Left("error msg 1")
else if (errorCondition2) Left("error msg 2")
else Right(42)
```

The idea of early returns or short-circuiting is inherent in for-comprehensions so here is an unconventional approach which converts `Booleans` to `Eithers` where `true` converts to `Left` via extension method

```
implicit class GuardToLeft(p: Boolean) {
  def toGuard[L](left: => L): Either[L, Unit] =
    if (p) Left(left) else Right(())
}
```

so now we can simulate traditional early return guards like so

```
for {
  _ <- errorCondition1.toGuard("error msg 1")
  _ <- errorCondition2.toGuard("error msg 2")
} yield {
  41 + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and answers. I guess it is just my aesthetic perception about multiple `if-else` being ugly since I have to add a level of indentation to the whole method just because of the first conditional.

Comment: Early returns are the cure for multiple indentations of `if` statements.

Comment: That's pretty unconventional.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's precisely one of the points I tried to make in my question. But how to implement early returns in Scala without using `return` statement?

Comment: Early return uses `return` by definition.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that made me grin. It also made me wonder about a breakable-like DSL that doesn't use the word `return`.

Answer (score 3):

The FP way is to use a type which has some form of error handling build in, e.g. `Either`.

Let's say that `String` is your error format. Then you can return early ("circuit break") using `flatMaps` - for `Either` `Left` is the error format, and `Right` is used for threading ongoing computation:

```
import scala.util._
def sqrtFromString(argument: String): Either[String, Double] = {
  val start: Either[String, String] = Right(argument) // just for upcasting Right to Either
  start
    // if start is Right,  then value inside it will be passed as string variable
    // Right will continue computation
    // Left will circuit break them
    .flatMap { string =>
      Try(string.toInt) match {
         case Success(int) => Right(int)
         case Failure(_)   => Left("Not integer")
      }
    }
    // if so far it is still Right, the value inside will be passed as int variable
    .flatMap { int =>
      if (int > 0) Right(int)
      else Left("Negative int")
    }
    // if Right, it still will be Right - no ability to circuit break using map
    .map { int =>
      Math.sqrt(int)
    }
}
```

Since `map` and `flatMap` are handled by `for` comprehension you could rewrite it to:

```
import scala.util._
def sqrtFromString(argument: String): Either[String, Double] =
  for {
    string <- (Right(argument): Either[String, String])
    int <- Try(string.toInt) match {
      case Success(int) => Right(int)
      case Failure(_)   => Left("Not integer")
    }
    positive <- {
      if (int > 0) Right(int)
      else Left("Negative int")
    }
  } yield Math.sqrt(positive)
```

which could be further shortened to:

```
def sqrtFromString(argument: String): Either[String, Double] =
  for {
    string <- Right(argument)
    int <- Try(string.toInt).toEither.left.map(_ => "Not integer")
    _ <- (if (int > 0) Right(()) else Left("Negative int"))
  } yield Math.sqrt(int)
```

The same principle works whether you are using `Try` or `Future` (they are like sync and async `Either` but with `Left` hardcoded to `Throwable` and build-in exception catching), `IO`, `Task`, `ZIO`, etc.

Comment: `scala.util` without plural.